# Generic methods and ambient declarations in TypeScript

Tags: generics, typescript

I would like to know if TypeScript allows generics on ambient declarations for methods.

**For example:**

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    // This works...
    define<T>(obj: any, item: T): void;
}

(() => {

    // TypeScript says "Cannot find name 'T'" here...
    Object.define<T> = (obj: any, item: T): void => {
        // ...
    }

})();
```

Is this allowed in TypeScript and if so, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of toying with the TypeScript playground is good for the soul...

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    // This works...
    define<T>(obj: any, item: T): void;
}

(() => {

    // TypeScript says "Cannot find name 'T'" here...
    Object.define = <T>(obj: any, item: T): void => {
        // ...
    }

})();
```